# Changing Python path variable in Openshift NodeJS cartridge

Tags: python, linux, node.js, openshift

I have a NodeJS web server (Express) locally that uses [Python-Shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell) to fire off Python scripts (mostly scraper stuff using [PyCurl](http://pycurl.io/)). The Python scripts also use various modules that I have installed using pip. This all works locally with no issues, running Node v4.1.1 and Python 2.7.10.

Now, I need a server to run this setup on, and I'm cheap, so I really want to use [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/), which I have used before for other Node-only projects.

My problem is that I need to work with Python, and while it is installed (v2.6 anyway), I can't do much with it. Pip is not installed at all, and I don't have administrative rights to install it. Easy_install seems to be present, but I get permission issues when trying to execute it (even just the test via "easy_install" with no parameters). I need pip to install several modules for my Python scripts.

I was able to follow the instructions [here](https://blog.openshift.com/enabling-python-27-on-a-paas-with-the-openshift-diy-app-type/) and get Python 2.7, setuptools, and pip all installed successfully, but they are only available by prefixing the path $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/bin (which resolves to /var/lib/openshift/[my-id]/app-root/data/bin). So...

```
\> $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

I can also successfully run my Python scripts if I prefix the python command with that path.

So my question is how can I either get python-shell to use that path for Python, or **how can I update Openshift's environment variables so that the standard "python" command is pointed to my manually-built v2.7.3 executable**?

I'm stumped, but I know next to nothing about Linux or Openshift's architecture specifically, so I'm hoping you guru's out there can help me out!

Comment: Just a note that it seems I was only able to install what I did because (per the instructions) I was in $OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR (the tmp directory). Is it safe to install modules here? Will they get removed in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone ever has a real answer to this, feel free to post it up, but I ended up just abandoning Python altogether and re-wrote the scraper in Node using [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio). Much better!